# Atom editor hyperclick not working

Tags: atom-editor

I installed hyperclick and js-hyperclick in Atom editor on OSX, but nothing is working. Moving mouse over words, pressing and releasing cmd  or option keys, nothing works ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Super unhelpful, but you could try taking a peek at the source code in the package... might clear things up. On Linux, I have to hold ctrl and wiggle my mouse a bit over the variables to get it to work. It's inconsistent for me, so one of these days, I'll fork it and make it better...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by also installing the hyperlink-hyperclick package as well as the hyperclick package.